# how can i use google login in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, google-signin

trying to use google login in vue 3 using vue3-google-login but i keep getting

```
 vue3_google_login__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useGoogleLogin) is not a function
    at setup
```

this is my component

```
  <div>
    <GoogleLogin
      :clientId="clientId"
      @success="handleGoogleLoginSuccess"
      @failure="handleGoogleLoginFailure"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { useGoogleLogin } from 'vue3-google-login';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const clientId = '5873015670';

    const { signIn } = useGoogleLogin({
      clientId,
      onSuccess: handleGoogleLoginSuccess,
      onFailure: handleGoogleLoginFailure,
    });
  },
});
</script>
```

please why do i keep getting the error ,what i'm i doing wrong

Comment: The error message is quite clear - there is no such function. Try using the component as described in the [documentation](https://yobaji.github.io/vue3-google-login/#initialize-the-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea for that try that.

First, install the `vue-google-signin-button` package using npm or yarn:

```
npm install vue-google-signin-button
```

Then, in your Vue component file, import the necessary dependencies:

```
import GoogleSignInButton from 'vue-google-signin-button'
```

Add the imported component to the `components` section of your Vue component:

```
components: {
  GoogleSignInButton
},
```

Now, you can use the google-signin-button component in your template section:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <google-signin-button
      :clientId="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
      @success="onSignInSuccess"
      @failure="onSignInFailure"
    ></google-signin-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Add the corresponding methods in the Vue component's `methods` section:

```
methods: {
  onSignInSuccess(googleUser) {
    // Handle successful sign-in
    console.log('Signed in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
  },
  onSignInFailure(error) {
    // Handle sign-in failure
    console.error('Sign-in failed:', error);
  }
}
```

More info about package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-signin-button