# how can i use vue3-google-login

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, google-oauth

i'm trying to use google login with these code but i dont know what i'm dooing wrong
this is how my api looks like,

```
app.get(
    '/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['email', 'profile']
    })
);

app.get(
    '/auth/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect: '/protected',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/google/failure',
    })
);
```

it works fine on my server side and saves to database

this is how my template looks like

```
<template>
  <button @click="login">Login Using Google</button>
</template>
<script setup>
import { googleSdkLoaded } from "vue3-google-login";
const login = () => {
  googleSdkLoaded((google) => {
    google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
      client_id: '58730156701-let.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'email profile openid',
      callback: (response) => {
        console.log("Handle the response", response);
        if (response.code) {
        //  sendCodeToBackend(response.code);
        }
      }
    }).requestCode();
  });
};
</script>
```

i get a code in my console

```
4/0AbUR2VNp3NmCBjF5nY9HApWF6FYFJ1Tg1jz2EqHw7tuZtG4yc78OE7U_Htm49_svtj7wtQ
```

please how can I send the code to my backend for authentication

Comment: That  duplicated question. Answer is here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76463968/how-can-i-use-google-login-in-vue3/76465117#76465117)

Comment: @Hakimov-dev doesnt work for me